# Manipulate's LocalizeVariables and initial values of variables

Tags: manipulate, syntax, options

```
Manipulate[a, {{a, 0.25, "label"}, 0, 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

The initial value is then set to `0`. On the other hand, if `LocalizeVariables` is `True`, the initial value is set to `0.25` as expected.

One could say that the behavior when `LocalizeVariables -> False` is expected because `DynamicModule[{a = 1}, ...` is not used to localize and set an initial value for it. But `DynamicModule[{}, ..., Initialization :> ( a = 1)]` would fit, wouldn't it?

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not received a clear answer from WRI Support yet so let's take this of the unanswered stack with a workaround for future visitors:

```
Manipulate[
  a
, {{a, 0.25, "label"}, 0, 1}
, Initialization :> (
    a = 0.25;
  )
, LocalizeVariables -> False
]
```